# Bandit algorithm probabilities: Evaluate $\int_{-\min_j \lambda_j}^\infty \frac{2}{(z+\lambda_i)^3}\exp(-\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{(z+\lambda_j)^2}) dz$

Tags: probability, integration, optimization, definite-integrals, algorithms

I am researching Bandit algorithms to apply them in my own research area. A very recent paper by Honda et. al [1] shows that Follow The Perturbed Leader algorithms can achieve the best of both worlds regret bounds, that is it works optimally for both the stochastic and the adversarial settings.

The way Bandit algorithms work is, that we are given $n$ doors and each time we open a door, we suffer a loss $\in [0, 1]$ from the opened door. The goal is to minimize the total loss accumulated by opening a door in each round. Obviously, a good algorithm would find out which door gives the lowest losses on average and open this door more often. Depending on the characteristics of the losses, stochastic and adversarial settings exist (also adversarially corrupted stochastic). More details can be found in [1].

In [1], the proposed algorithm has the probability of selecting a door expressed by the given integral below. In the paper, the authors propose to first pick a door using the algorithm randomly, then repeat the same random sampling procedure many times until the same door is picked. The number of trials before picking the same door will estimate the reciprocal of the probability of picking that door, which can be used as an approximate estimate in the algorithm. However, the number of trials is $n$ on average and the sampling procedure also takes $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time. Thus, the complexity of approximately determining probabilities becomes $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ on average, which is too high for my application.

Thus, given $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \geq 0$, is there a way to find a closed-form solution for the following integral, given any $i \in \{1, \dots, n\}$:

$$p_i(\lambda) = \int_{-\min_j \lambda_j}^\infty \frac{2}{(z+\lambda_i)^3}\exp \Big(-\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{(z+\lambda_j)^2}\Big) dz$$

and if not, what is the easiest way to evaluate this integral numerically? This integral is from Equation 1 in [1]. If I could somehow convert this integral into a sum that converges very quickly, then I could easily evaluate it numerically (programmatically) but have no idea what kind of approach would work.

Note: The integral is related to the maximum of $n$ Frechet random variables [2] with shifted locations, thus the terms are coming from the pdf and cdf of such random variables.

[1] https://proceedings.mlr.press/v201/honda23a.html

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution